# Linguagem R - Separação de colunas

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, tidyr

Tenho as duas colunas abaixo e preciso separá-las para que os dígitos fiquem em outras colunas. A ideia é ter no final 4 colunas com nomes de times e score.

Duas colunas do df2 tipo character:

```
Time1           Time2
Green Bay 35  Kansas City 10
Green Bay 33      Oakland 14
```

Preciso que os dígitos estejam separados, porém quando uso a função abaixo, ele come um dígito e me retorna apenas "3" e não "35" por exemplo:

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  separate(Time1, into = c("Time", "Score"), sep = "\\d",
           extra = "merge")
```

Sabem alguma forma de corrigir?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eis três maneiras de separar as palavras dos números nas duas colunas. A primeira utiliza `sub`, a segunda e a terceira `str_extract` do pacote `stringr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(
    Score1 = sub("^.* (\\b[^ ]+)$", "\\1", Time1),
    Time1 = sub(" [^ ]*$", "", Time1),
    Score2 = sub("^.* (\\b[^ ]+)$", "\\1", Time2),
    Time2 = sub(" [^ ]*$", "", Time2)
  )

df2 %>%
  mutate(
    Score1 = str_extract(Time1, pattern = "[[:digit:]]+"),
    Time1 = str_extract(Time1, pattern = "[[:alpha:][:blank:]]*"),
    Score2 = str_extract(Time2, pattern = "[[:digit:]]+"),
    Time2 = str_extract(Time2, pattern = "[[:alpha:][:blank:]]*")
  )
```

Esta terceira maneira *nega* o padrão `[:digit:]` para extrair as palavras. Por isso, talvez tenha as regex's mais claras.

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(
    Score1 = str_extract(Time1, pattern = "[[:digit:]]+"),
    Time1 = str_extract(Time1, pattern = "[^[:digit:]]*"),
    Score2 = str_extract(Time2, pattern = "[[:digit:]]+"),
    Time2 = str_extract(Time2, pattern = "[^[:digit:]]*")
  )
```

---

### Dados

```
txt <- "Time1           Time2
'Green Bay 35'  'Kansas City 10'
'Green Bay 33'      'Oakland 14'"
df2 <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = TRUE)
```